# Read numbers separated by comma and write them to a file separated by tab

Tags: c++

Given an input file such as:

```
 5,6
 3,4
 4,7
```

I want to convert it to the following output where the numbers are separated by a tab:

```
 5  6
 3  4
 4  7
```

I have the following code which reads the input file and tries to write the output file:

```
std::ofstream outputFile("test.txt");

if (outputFile.is_open()) {

    while(std::getline(infile, line, ',')) {
        std::stringstream   linestream(line);
        int val1;
        int val2;

        linestream >> val1 >> val2;
        outputFile << val1 << "\t" << val2 << "\n";
    }
}
```

The problem is that my output file contains:

```
 1       -1431507824
 3       5
 6       6
 2       6
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are delimiting by comma, thus only reading one value in the first call. One possible fix is to read a line up to newline and then explicitly read in the comma between the two values:

```
while(std::getline(infile, line)) {
    std::stringstream   linestream(line);
    int val1;
    int val2;
    char comma;
    linestream >> val1 >> comma >> val2;
    outputFile << val1 << "\t" << val2 << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you add ',' as Explicit delimiting character.

and Here what's you want

```
int main(){
        std::ofstream outputFile("test.txt");
        std::istringstream input;
        input.str("5,6\n3,4\n4,7\n");
        string line;
        stringstream linestream;
            while(getline(input, line)) {
                std::stringstream   linestream(line);
                int val1;
                int val2;
                char comma;         
                linestream >> val1>> comma >> val2;
                outputFile << val1 << "\t" << val2 << "\n";
        }
}
```

Output:

```
5   6
3   4
4   7
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to edit my question (I made a mistake)

Comment: Ok you not to use getline(infile, line, ',')

Comment: This answer is still incorrect. First of all "*you should use `'\n'` or nothing*" is plain wrong, since the usage of other delimiters can be justified. Secondly, this does not solve the problem, but introduces another one. Why didn't you run your own code to see whether or not it works before posting it here?

Comment: I change it @Fureeish Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With

```
std::getline(linestream, data, ',');
```

you read everything up to the first comma in the stream. This data is discarded by you.

Then when you do

```
linestream >> val1 >> val2;
```

you read the remaining value into `val1`, and then the extraction will fail for `val2` since there's nothing more to read. That will lead `val2` to be *uninitialized* and have an *indeterminate* value.

A simple solution is to simply convert the string in `data` (using [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)) and assign to `val1` (since that's the value it contains), and then read the remaining value into `val2`. Something like

```
std::getline(linestream, data, ',');
val1 = std::stoi(data);
linestream >> val2;
```

---

With your edit, the above answer is only *partially* valid. The solution is basically the same though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to edit my question (I made a mistake). I'll look into this! Thanks